# Good text foreground color for a given background color

Tags: user-interface, text, colors, background-color

I'm drawing a color selection button and I'm looking for a nice and simple formula to get a good text color (foreground) for a given background color in RGB.

A simple try would be to just take the complement color but this will produce an odd looking button for colors like pure blue or pure red.
Is there something well known that does this?

If it matters at all, I'm using QT.

Comment: Also, complementary colors have the problem that gray maps to gray.

Comment: This accessible colors tool might help: http://accessible-colors.com

Answer (score 142, accepted):

For maximum legibility, you want maximum brightness contrast without getting into hues which don't work together. The most consistent way to do this is to stick with **black** or **white** for the text color. You might be able to come up with more aesthetically pleasing schemes, but none of them will be more legible.

To pick between black or white, you need to know the brightness of the background. This gets a little more complicated, due to two factors:

- The perceived brightness of the individual primaries red, green, and blue are not identical. The quickest advice I can give is to use the traditional formula to convert RGB to gray - R*0.299 + G*0.587 + B*0.114. There are lots of other formulas.
- The gamma curve applied to displays makes the middle gray value higher than you'd expect. This is easily solved by using 186 as the middle value rather than 128. Anything less than 186 should use white text, anything greater than 186 should use black text.

Comment: Let's say that we have a background colour that sits right in the middle of the grayscale spectrum. Isn't this colour gamma-encoded by the system before being gamma-decoded by the monitor? If so, why would we apply a second layer of gamma-decoding by setting the midpoint to 186? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @LeviBotelho, no the system does not do gamma encoding - all the RGB values it works with are assumed to be gamma encoded already. On a properly calibrated monitor you will find that alternating lines of 0/255 will be the same brightness as a gray block of 186. Since most monitors aren't calibrated this will vary somewhat, for example my own is closer to 167.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Good example with the alternating lines!

Comment: Note to everybody: if you need W3C compliance please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/5987.

Answer (score 11):

I'm no expert on programming things related to RGB, but from a designer's perspective, often the most readable color will be just a much lighter (if the background color is dark) or darker (if the background color is light) version of the same shade.

Basically you'd take your RGB values and if they're closer to 0 (dark) you'd push them each up by an equal amount for your foreground color, or vice versa if it's a light BG.

Complement colors can actually be really painful on the eyes for readability.

Comment: I agree with this, go for a darker or lighter shade of the same colour. This would also be easy to do programmaticaly

Comment: Mind the [daltonic people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness). One of my University teachers, as an example, had great difficulty distinguishing shades of blue.

Comment: The most effective way to do this is to use opacity rather than actually changing the RGB values. So if you want the text to be lighter, use a transparent white, and for darker a transparent black. https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-text-background-colors

Answer (score 9):

**Leverage an outline for legibility**

If by *"good text color (foreground)"* you intend it for **legibility** purposes when the user chooses `any background colour`, you can always produce white text having a black outline. It will be legible on any solid, patterned or gradient background, from black through white and anything in between.

[image]

Even if this doesn't hit the mark of your intention, I think it worthwhile posted here because I came looking for similar solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Building on top of Mark's response, here's some Ruby code that'll do the work

```rb
rgbval = "8A23C0".hex
r = rgbval >> 16
g = (rgbval & 65280) >> 8
b = rgbval & 255
brightness = r*0.299 + g*0.587 + b*0.114
return (brightness > 160) ? "#000" : "#fff"
```

Comment: Qt/c++ equivalent: auto brightness = brush.redF() * 0.299 + brush.greenF() * 0.587 +
                          brush.blueF() * 0.114;
        painter.setPen((brightness > 0.6) ? Qt::black : Qt::white);  // text

Answer (score 3):

You are better off with a high difference in luminosity. In general, colored backgrounds with colored text suck for readability, hurting the eyes over time. Lightly tinted colors (e.g. in HSB, S~10%, B>90%) with black text work fine, or lightly tinted text over a black background. I'd stay away from coloring both. Dark text (b~30%, s>50%) with a subtle coloration over a white background can also be fine. Yellow (amber) text on a deep blue background has excellent readability, as does amber or green on black. This is why old dumbterms (vt100, vt52, etc.) went for these colors.

If you really need to do color-on-color for the 'look', you could reverse both H and B, while pinning saturation at a moderate to low level.

And one last note: if you have a 50% gray background, rethink your interface. You're robbing yourself of half your dynamic range! You're alienating low-visibility users, including anyone over 35...

Answer (score 2):

Color combinations often look terrible when not carefully chosen. Why not use either white or black for the text, depending on the Brightness of the color. (Will need to convert to HSB first.)

Or let the user choose either black or white text.

Or use pre-defined combinations. This is what Google does in their calendar product.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a simailr answer and came across this post and some others that I thought I'd share. According to http://juicystudio.com/services/luminositycontrastratio.php#specify the "Success Criterion 1.4.3 of WCAG 2.0 requires the visual presentation of text and images of text has a contrast ratio of at least 4.5:1" with some exceptions. That site lets you put in foreground and background colors to compute their contrast, although it would be helpful if it would suggest alternatives or ranges.

One of the best sites I've found for visualizing color contrast is http://colorizer.org/ It lets you adjust almost all manner of color scales (RGB, CMYK, etc.) at the same time and then shows you the result on the screen, such as white text on a yellow background.

Comment: I found this is good to for test, rather than on design phase

Answer (score 0):

I usually look at color complements, they also have color complement wheels to help

http://www.makart.com/resources/artclass/cwheel.html

If your color is HSL, flip the Hue by 180 degrees for a decent calculation

Comment: Give me an application with green text on a red background (or vice versa) and you'll find out where I've buried the other bodies.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put @MarkRansom's answer into use and managed to create this snippet:

I got the values From seeing how sRGB converts to CIE XYZ and built upon that.
The script simply tracks the position of the foreground item and it's position regarding the colored background items.

Then based on background luminosity it gradually changes the foreground text color to either black or white.

Open the codepen for full example
https://codepen.io/AndrewKnife/pen/XWBggQq

```js
const calculateLight = (colorItem: number) => {
  let c = colorItem / 255.0;
  if (c <= 0.03928) {
    c /= 12.92;
  } else {
    c = Math.pow((c + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4);
  }
  return c;
};

const calculateLuminosity = (color: RGBColor) => {
  return (
    0.2126 * calculateLight(color.r) +
    0.7152 * calculateLight(color.g) +
    0.0722 * calculateLight(color.b)
  );
};

const getContrastColor = (color: RGBColor) => {
  if (calculateLuminosity(color) > LUMINOSITY_LIMIT) {
    return FONT_COLOR_DARK;
  }
  return FONT_COLOR_LIGHT;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I thing that converting to HSV might be the way, but IMO changing hue would look weird. I'd try keeping the hue and fiddling with value and maybe saturation (light red buttons with dark red text ... hm sounds scary :-) ).