# Changing background color and text

Tags: asp.net, jquery

In the webform1 by using a color picker i have choosing a color.In the webform2 the color should be appeared as background color and if there is any letters or text in the webform2 it have to change as an opposite color.

for example:

background is black text is white.
background is blue text is red.

in a gmail settings themes are there if we change a theme background is different
color and text is another color.but in that themes colors are already fixed for background and text.but we using color picker

please advise me.

Thanks

Comment: Post your current code.

Answer (score 0):

This stack overflow question might have some answers for you.

[Given a background color, how to get a foreground color that makes it readable on that background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116260/given-a-background-color-how-to-get-a-foreground-color-that-make-it-readable-on)

Possible other solutions include:

1. Add picker for foreground color.
2. Create preset foreground colors for each available background color.