# How do I change text-color determined by the background color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, hex

I'm looking for a way, with jQuery ideally, to determine the correct text color, based on the brightness of the background color?

E.g. white background, black text colour. I believe this could be done crudely with adding the HEX value and guesstimating but does anyone know a better way or jQuery way to do this?

Comment: and what with gray (#808080) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decide font color in white or black depending on background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942878/how-to-decide-font-color-in-white-or-black-depending-on-background-color)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can try inverting the hex value of the color. So `#FFFFFF` becomes `#000000` and `#AAAAAA` becomes `#555555`. Of course, this method falls through when you have `#888888` which when inverted, gives you `#777777` (they don't contrast as much).

This [blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/IdealTextColor.aspx) describes another way (they only use black or white for the foreground color, depending on the background color). I've translated it into Javascript:

```
function idealTextColor(bgColor) {

   var nThreshold = 105;
   var components = getRGBComponents(bgColor);
   var bgDelta = (components.R * 0.299) + (components.G * 0.587) + (components.B * 0.114);

   return ((255 - bgDelta) < nThreshold) ? "#000000" : "#ffffff";   
}

function getRGBComponents(color) {       

    var r = color.substring(1, 3);
    var g = color.substring(3, 5);
    var b = color.substring(5, 7);

    return {
       R: parseInt(r, 16),
       G: parseInt(g, 16),
       B: parseInt(b, 16)
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this informative answer, I'm just having a look at your suggested code translation and I'm getting "missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error] int bgDelta = (components.R * 0.2...mponents.G * 0.587) + (bg.B * 0.114);" - however I can't see that missing ;? does it work for you?

Comment: @WiseDonkey Oops, I've updated it. When I was translating, I forgot to change a `bg` into `components`, an `int` into `var`, and I used semicolons instead of commas in `getRGBComponents`.

Comment: const idealTextColor = ([a, b, c]: number[]) => (150 < (a * 0.299) + (b * 0.587) + (c * 0.114)) ? "black" : "white";

Answer (score 0):

If you use Typescript you can use this function:

```
setFontColor(bgColor){
  let r = bgColor.substring(1, 3);
  let g = bgColor.substring(3, 5);
  let b = bgColor.substring(5, 7);

  const bgDelta = (parseInt(r, 16) * 0.299) + (parseInt(g, 16) * 0.587) + (parseInt(b, 16) * 0.114);
  return ((255 - bgDelta) < 105) ? "#000" : "#fff"; }
```

In the HTML (Like Angular):

```
<div class="color-bg" [style.color]="true? setFontColor(color) : '#000'">
    your text
</div>
```

My result:

[image]