# Colour chart for Tkinter and Tix

Tags: python, tkinter, tix

I wanted to visualise some basic colours, so I could pick the appropriate ones for my colour scheme. I couldn't find a colour chart anywhere so modified a sample to display it.

Is this a good way to do it?

```
import Tix as tk
# import tkinter.tix as tk # for Python 3

 
COLORS  =['snow', 'ghost white', 'white smoke', 'gainsboro', 'floral white', 'old lace',
    'linen', 'antique white', 'papaya whip', 'blanched almond', 'bisque', 'peach puff',
    'navajo white', 'lemon chiffon', 'mint cream', 'azure', 'alice blue', 'lavender',
    'lavender blush', 'misty rose', 'dark slate gray', 'dim gray', 'slate gray',
    'light slate gray', 'gray', 'light grey', 'midnight blue', 'navy', 'cornflower blue', 'dark slate blue',
    'slate blue', 'medium slate blue', 'light slate blue', 'medium blue', 'royal blue',  'blue',
    'dodger blue', 'deep sky blue', 'sky blue', 'light sky blue', 'steel blue', 'light steel blue',
    'light blue', 'powder blue', 'pale turquoise', 'dark turquoise', 'medium turquoise', 'turquoise',
    'cyan', 'light cyan', 'cadet blue', 'medium aquamarine', 'aquamarine', 'dark green', 'dark olive green',
    'dark sea green', 'sea green', 'medium sea green', 'light sea green', 'pale green', 'spring green',
    'lawn green', 'medium spring green', 'green yellow', 'lime green', 'yellow green',
    'forest green', 'olive drab', 'dark khaki', 'khaki', 'pale goldenrod', 'light goldenrod yellow',
    'light yellow', 'yellow', 'gold', 'light goldenrod', 'goldenrod', 'dark goldenrod', 'rosy brown',
    'indian red', 'saddle brown', 'sandy brown',
    'dark salmon', 'salmon', 'light salmon', 'orange', 'dark orange',
    'coral', 'light coral', 'tomato', 'orange red', 'red', 'hot pink', 'deep pink', 'pink', 'light pink',
    'pale violet red', 'maroon', 'medium violet red', 'violet red',
    'medium orchid', 'dark orchid', 'dark violet', 'blue violet', 'purple', 'medium purple',
    'thistle', 'snow2', 'snow3',
    'snow4', 'seashell2', 'seashell3', 'seashell4', 'AntiqueWhite1', 'AntiqueWhite2',
    'AntiqueWhite3', 'AntiqueWhite4', 'bisque2', 'bisque3', 'bisque4', 'PeachPuff2',
    'PeachPuff3', 'PeachPuff4', 'NavajoWhite2', 'NavajoWhite3', 'NavajoWhite4',
    'LemonChiffon2', 'LemonChiffon3', 'LemonChiffon4', 'cornsilk2', 'cornsilk3',
    'cornsilk4', 'ivory2', 'ivory3', 'ivory4', 'honeydew2', 'honeydew3', 'honeydew4',
    'LavenderBlush2', 'LavenderBlush3', 'LavenderBlush4', 'MistyRose2', 'MistyRose3',
    'MistyRose4', 'azure2', 'azure3', 'azure4', 'SlateBlue1', 'SlateBlue2', 'SlateBlue3',
    'SlateBlue4', 'RoyalBlue1', 'RoyalBlue2', 'RoyalBlue3', 'RoyalBlue4', 'blue2', 'blue4',
    'DodgerBlue2', 'DodgerBlue3', 'DodgerBlue4', 'SteelBlue1', 'SteelBlue2',
    'SteelBlue3', 'SteelBlue4', 'DeepSkyBlue2', 'DeepSkyBlue3', 'DeepSkyBlue4',
    'SkyBlue1', 'SkyBlue2', 'SkyBlue3', 'SkyBlue4', 'LightSkyBlue1', 'LightSkyBlue2',
    'LightSkyBlue3', 'LightSkyBlue4', 'SlateGray1', 'SlateGray2', 'SlateGray3',
    'SlateGray4', 'LightSteelBlue1', 'LightSteelBlue2', 'LightSteelBlue3',
    'LightSteelBlue4', 'LightBlue1', 'LightBlue2', 'LightBlue3', 'LightBlue4',
    'LightCyan2', 'LightCyan3', 'LightCyan4', 'PaleTurquoise1', 'PaleTurquoise2',
    'PaleTurquoise3', 'PaleTurquoise4', 'CadetBlue1', 'CadetBlue2', 'CadetBlue3',
    'CadetBlue4', 'turquoise1', 'turquoise2', 'turquoise3', 'turquoise4', 'cyan2', 'cyan3',
    'cyan4', 'DarkSlateGray1', 'DarkSlateGray2', 'DarkSlateGray3', 'DarkSlateGray4',
    'aquamarine2', 'aquamarine4', 'DarkSeaGreen1', 'DarkSeaGreen2', 'DarkSeaGreen3',
    'DarkSeaGreen4', 'SeaGreen1', 'SeaGreen2', 'SeaGreen3', 'PaleGreen1', 'PaleGreen2',
    'PaleGreen3', 'PaleGreen4', 'SpringGreen2', 'SpringGreen3', 'SpringGreen4',
    'green2', 'green3', 'green4', 'chartreuse2', 'chartreuse3', 'chartreuse4',
    'OliveDrab1', 'OliveDrab2', 'OliveDrab4', 'DarkOliveGreen1', 'DarkOliveGreen2',
    'DarkOliveGreen3', 'DarkOliveGreen4', 'khaki1', 'khaki2', 'khaki3', 'khaki4',
    'LightGoldenrod1', 'LightGoldenrod2', 'LightGoldenrod3', 'LightGoldenrod4',
    'LightYellow2', 'LightYellow3', 'LightYellow4', 'yellow2', 'yellow3', 'yellow4',
    'gold2', 'gold3', 'gold4', 'goldenrod1', 'goldenrod2', 'goldenrod3', 'goldenrod4',
    'DarkGoldenrod1', 'DarkGoldenrod2', 'DarkGoldenrod3', 'DarkGoldenrod4',
    'RosyBrown1', 'RosyBrown2', 'RosyBrown3', 'RosyBrown4', 'IndianRed1', 'IndianRed2',
    'IndianRed3', 'IndianRed4', 'sienna1', 'sienna2', 'sienna3', 'sienna4', 'burlywood1',
    'burlywood2', 'burlywood3', 'burlywood4', 'wheat1', 'wheat2', 'wheat3', 'wheat4', 'tan1',
    'tan2', 'tan4', 'chocolate1', 'chocolate2', 'chocolate3', 'firebrick1', 'firebrick2',
    'firebrick3', 'firebrick4', 'brown1', 'brown2', 'brown3', 'brown4', 'salmon1', 'salmon2',
    'salmon3', 'salmon4', 'LightSalmon2', 'LightSalmon3', 'LightSalmon4', 'orange2',
    'orange3', 'orange4', 'DarkOrange1', 'DarkOrange2', 'DarkOrange3', 'DarkOrange4',
    'coral1', 'coral2', 'coral3', 'coral4', 'tomato2', 'tomato3', 'tomato4', 'OrangeRed2',
    'OrangeRed3', 'OrangeRed4', 'red2', 'red3', 'red4', 'DeepPink2', 'DeepPink3', 'DeepPink4',
    'HotPink1', 'HotPink2', 'HotPink3', 'HotPink4', 'pink1', 'pink2', 'pink3', 'pink4',
    'LightPink1', 'LightPink2', 'LightPink3', 'LightPink4', 'PaleVioletRed1',
    'PaleVioletRed2', 'PaleVioletRed3', 'PaleVioletRed4', 'maroon1', 'maroon2',
    'maroon3', 'maroon4', 'VioletRed1', 'VioletRed2', 'VioletRed3', 'VioletRed4',
    'magenta2', 'magenta3', 'magenta4', 'orchid1', 'orchid2', 'orchid3', 'orchid4', 'plum1',
    'plum2', 'plum3', 'plum4', 'MediumOrchid1', 'MediumOrchid2', 'MediumOrchid3',
    'MediumOrchid4', 'DarkOrchid1', 'DarkOrchid2', 'DarkOrchid3', 'DarkOrchid4',
    'purple1', 'purple2', 'purple3', 'purple4', 'MediumPurple1', 'MediumPurple2',
    'MediumPurple3', 'MediumPurple4', 'thistle1', 'thistle2', 'thistle3', 'thistle4',
    'gray1', 'gray2', 'gray3', 'gray4', 'gray5', 'gray6', 'gray7', 'gray8', 'gray9', 'gray10',
    'gray11', 'gray12', 'gray13', 'gray14', 'gray15', 'gray16', 'gray17', 'gray18', 'gray19',
    'gray20', 'gray21', 'gray22', 'gray23', 'gray24', 'gray25', 'gray26', 'gray27', 'gray28',
    'gray29', 'gray30', 'gray31', 'gray32', 'gray33', 'gray34', 'gray35', 'gray36', 'gray37',
    'gray38', 'gray39', 'gray40', 'gray42', 'gray43', 'gray44', 'gray45', 'gray46', 'gray47',
    'gray48', 'gray49', 'gray50', 'gray51', 'gray52', 'gray53', 'gray54', 'gray55', 'gray56',
    'gray57', 'gray58', 'gray59', 'gray60', 'gray61', 'gray62', 'gray63', 'gray64', 'gray65',
    'gray66', 'gray67', 'gray68', 'gray69', 'gray70', 'gray71', 'gray72', 'gray73', 'gray74',
    'gray75', 'gray76', 'gray77', 'gray78', 'gray79', 'gray80', 'gray81', 'gray82', 'gray83',
    'gray84', 'gray85', 'gray86', 'gray87', 'gray88', 'gray89', 'gray90', 'gray91', 'gray92',
    'gray93', 'gray94', 'gray95', 'gray97', 'gray98', 'gray99']


def drawframes(_sw):
    for c in COLORS:
        e= tk.Label(sw.window, text = c, background = c)
        e.pack(fill = tk.X)

r= tk.Tk()
r.title("Named colour chart")
sw= tk.ScrolledWindow(r, scrollbar=tk.BOTH)
sw.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

drawframes(sw)

r.mainloop()
```

Comment: this would be more useful if it didn't require tix.

Comment: I use Tix to draw a scrollable window but that's all. Why would it be better if I didn't use Tix? Is Tix shunned in the python community?

Comment: It would be nicer if darker colours had white text, since some (eg. `grey1`) are very hard to see, but I appreciate that this was not meant to be very complex.

Answer (score 40):

For what it's worth, here's a version that doesn't require `Tix`.  It uses a `grid` manager so you can see all the colors at the same time. You may want to adjust `MAX_ROWS` and `FONT_SIZE` for your display.

```
import tkinter as tk

COLORS = ['snow', 'ghost white', 'white smoke', 'gainsboro', 'floral white', 'old lace',
          'linen', 'antique white', 'papaya whip', 'blanched almond', 'bisque', 'peach puff',
          'navajo white', 'lemon chiffon', 'mint cream', 'azure', 'alice blue', 'lavender',
          'lavender blush', 'misty rose', 'dark slate gray', 'dim gray', 'slate gray',
          'light slate gray', 'gray', 'light grey', 'midnight blue', 'navy', 'cornflower blue', 'dark slate blue',
          'slate blue', 'medium slate blue', 'light slate blue', 'medium blue', 'royal blue',  'blue',
          'dodger blue', 'deep sky blue', 'sky blue', 'light sky blue', 'steel blue', 'light steel blue',
          'light blue', 'powder blue', 'pale turquoise', 'dark turquoise', 'medium turquoise', 'turquoise',
          'cyan', 'light cyan', 'cadet blue', 'medium aquamarine', 'aquamarine', 'dark green', 'dark olive green',
          'dark sea green', 'sea green', 'medium sea green', 'light sea green', 'pale green', 'spring green',
          'lawn green', 'medium spring green', 'green yellow', 'lime green', 'yellow green',
          'forest green', 'olive drab', 'dark khaki', 'khaki', 'pale goldenrod', 'light goldenrod yellow',
          'light yellow', 'yellow', 'gold', 'light goldenrod', 'goldenrod', 'dark goldenrod', 'rosy brown',
          'indian red', 'saddle brown', 'sandy brown',
          'dark salmon', 'salmon', 'light salmon', 'orange', 'dark orange',
          'coral', 'light coral', 'tomato', 'orange red', 'red', 'hot pink', 'deep pink', 'pink', 'light pink',
          'pale violet red', 'maroon', 'medium violet red', 'violet red',
          'medium orchid', 'dark orchid', 'dark violet', 'blue violet', 'purple', 'medium purple',
          'thistle', 'snow2', 'snow3',
          'snow4', 'seashell2', 'seashell3', 'seashell4', 'AntiqueWhite1', 'AntiqueWhite2',
          'AntiqueWhite3', 'AntiqueWhite4', 'bisque2', 'bisque3', 'bisque4', 'PeachPuff2',
          'PeachPuff3', 'PeachPuff4', 'NavajoWhite2', 'NavajoWhite3', 'NavajoWhite4',
          'LemonChiffon2', 'LemonChiffon3', 'LemonChiffon4', 'cornsilk2', 'cornsilk3',
          'cornsilk4', 'ivory2', 'ivory3', 'ivory4', 'honeydew2', 'honeydew3', 'honeydew4',
          'LavenderBlush2', 'LavenderBlush3', 'LavenderBlush4', 'MistyRose2', 'MistyRose3',
          'MistyRose4', 'azure2', 'azure3', 'azure4', 'SlateBlue1', 'SlateBlue2', 'SlateBlue3',
          'SlateBlue4', 'RoyalBlue1', 'RoyalBlue2', 'RoyalBlue3', 'RoyalBlue4', 'blue2', 'blue4',
          'DodgerBlue2', 'DodgerBlue3', 'DodgerBlue4', 'SteelBlue1', 'SteelBlue2',
          'SteelBlue3', 'SteelBlue4', 'DeepSkyBlue2', 'DeepSkyBlue3', 'DeepSkyBlue4',
          'SkyBlue1', 'SkyBlue2', 'SkyBlue3', 'SkyBlue4', 'LightSkyBlue1', 'LightSkyBlue2',
          'LightSkyBlue3', 'LightSkyBlue4', 'SlateGray1', 'SlateGray2', 'SlateGray3',
          'SlateGray4', 'LightSteelBlue1', 'LightSteelBlue2', 'LightSteelBlue3',
          'LightSteelBlue4', 'LightBlue1', 'LightBlue2', 'LightBlue3', 'LightBlue4',
          'LightCyan2', 'LightCyan3', 'LightCyan4', 'PaleTurquoise1', 'PaleTurquoise2',
          'PaleTurquoise3', 'PaleTurquoise4', 'CadetBlue1', 'CadetBlue2', 'CadetBlue3',
          'CadetBlue4', 'turquoise1', 'turquoise2', 'turquoise3', 'turquoise4', 'cyan2', 'cyan3',
          'cyan4', 'DarkSlateGray1', 'DarkSlateGray2', 'DarkSlateGray3', 'DarkSlateGray4',
          'aquamarine2', 'aquamarine4', 'DarkSeaGreen1', 'DarkSeaGreen2', 'DarkSeaGreen3',
          'DarkSeaGreen4', 'SeaGreen1', 'SeaGreen2', 'SeaGreen3', 'PaleGreen1', 'PaleGreen2',
          'PaleGreen3', 'PaleGreen4', 'SpringGreen2', 'SpringGreen3', 'SpringGreen4',
          'green2', 'green3', 'green4', 'chartreuse2', 'chartreuse3', 'chartreuse4',
          'OliveDrab1', 'OliveDrab2', 'OliveDrab4', 'DarkOliveGreen1', 'DarkOliveGreen2',
          'DarkOliveGreen3', 'DarkOliveGreen4', 'khaki1', 'khaki2', 'khaki3', 'khaki4',
          'LightGoldenrod1', 'LightGoldenrod2', 'LightGoldenrod3', 'LightGoldenrod4',
          'LightYellow2', 'LightYellow3', 'LightYellow4', 'yellow2', 'yellow3', 'yellow4',
          'gold2', 'gold3', 'gold4', 'goldenrod1', 'goldenrod2', 'goldenrod3', 'goldenrod4',
          'DarkGoldenrod1', 'DarkGoldenrod2', 'DarkGoldenrod3', 'DarkGoldenrod4',
          'RosyBrown1', 'RosyBrown2', 'RosyBrown3', 'RosyBrown4', 'IndianRed1', 'IndianRed2',
          'IndianRed3', 'IndianRed4', 'sienna1', 'sienna2', 'sienna3', 'sienna4', 'burlywood1',
          'burlywood2', 'burlywood3', 'burlywood4', 'wheat1', 'wheat2', 'wheat3', 'wheat4', 'tan1',
          'tan2', 'tan4', 'chocolate1', 'chocolate2', 'chocolate3', 'firebrick1', 'firebrick2',
          'firebrick3', 'firebrick4', 'brown1', 'brown2', 'brown3', 'brown4', 'salmon1', 'salmon2',
          'salmon3', 'salmon4', 'LightSalmon2', 'LightSalmon3', 'LightSalmon4', 'orange2',
          'orange3', 'orange4', 'DarkOrange1', 'DarkOrange2', 'DarkOrange3', 'DarkOrange4',
          'coral1', 'coral2', 'coral3', 'coral4', 'tomato2', 'tomato3', 'tomato4', 'OrangeRed2',
          'OrangeRed3', 'OrangeRed4', 'red2', 'red3', 'red4', 'DeepPink2', 'DeepPink3', 'DeepPink4',
          'HotPink1', 'HotPink2', 'HotPink3', 'HotPink4', 'pink1', 'pink2', 'pink3', 'pink4',
          'LightPink1', 'LightPink2', 'LightPink3', 'LightPink4', 'PaleVioletRed1',
          'PaleVioletRed2', 'PaleVioletRed3', 'PaleVioletRed4', 'maroon1', 'maroon2',
          'maroon3', 'maroon4', 'VioletRed1', 'VioletRed2', 'VioletRed3', 'VioletRed4',
          'magenta2', 'magenta3', 'magenta4', 'orchid1', 'orchid2', 'orchid3', 'orchid4', 'plum1',
          'plum2', 'plum3', 'plum4', 'MediumOrchid1', 'MediumOrchid2', 'MediumOrchid3',
          'MediumOrchid4', 'DarkOrchid1', 'DarkOrchid2', 'DarkOrchid3', 'DarkOrchid4',
          'purple1', 'purple2', 'purple3', 'purple4', 'MediumPurple1', 'MediumPurple2',
          'MediumPurple3', 'MediumPurple4', 'thistle1', 'thistle2', 'thistle3', 'thistle4',
          'gray1', 'gray2', 'gray3', 'gray4', 'gray5', 'gray6', 'gray7', 'gray8', 'gray9', 'gray10',
          'gray11', 'gray12', 'gray13', 'gray14', 'gray15', 'gray16', 'gray17', 'gray18', 'gray19',
          'gray20', 'gray21', 'gray22', 'gray23', 'gray24', 'gray25', 'gray26', 'gray27', 'gray28',
          'gray29', 'gray30', 'gray31', 'gray32', 'gray33', 'gray34', 'gray35', 'gray36', 'gray37',
          'gray38', 'gray39', 'gray40', 'gray42', 'gray43', 'gray44', 'gray45', 'gray46', 'gray47',
          'gray48', 'gray49', 'gray50', 'gray51', 'gray52', 'gray53', 'gray54', 'gray55', 'gray56',
          'gray57', 'gray58', 'gray59', 'gray60', 'gray61', 'gray62', 'gray63', 'gray64', 'gray65',
          'gray66', 'gray67', 'gray68', 'gray69', 'gray70', 'gray71', 'gray72', 'gray73', 'gray74',
          'gray75', 'gray76', 'gray77', 'gray78', 'gray79', 'gray80', 'gray81', 'gray82', 'gray83',
          'gray84', 'gray85', 'gray86', 'gray87', 'gray88', 'gray89', 'gray90', 'gray91', 'gray92',
          'gray93', 'gray94', 'gray95', 'gray97', 'gray98', 'gray99']


class ColorChart(tk.Frame):

    MAX_ROWS = 36
    FONT_SIZE = 10

    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        r = 0
        c = 0

        for color in COLORS:
            label = tk.Label(self, text=color, bg=color,
                             font=("Times", self.FONT_SIZE, "bold"))
            label.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky="ew")
            r += 1

            if r > self.MAX_ROWS:
                r = 0
                c += 1

        self.pack(expand=1, fill="both")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Named Color Chart")
    app = ColorChart(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 12):

There is also the *official colour names* documented in the [colours man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/colors.html) for Tk.

Comment: Ideally that page would also have actual samples of each colour next to each name.

Answer (score 8):

What about reading COLORS from a file ?

```
import sys, os
rgb_path = [
    "/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt", #Linux
    "/usr/X11/share/X11/rgb.txt", #MacOS
    ]
COLORS = []
for filename in rgb_path:
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as filedesc:
            for line in filedesc:
                if not (line.isspace() or line.startswith("#")):
                    # take the part after the last \t rsplit("\t",[-1])
                    # and remove the carriage return character [:-1]
                    COLORS.append(line.rsplit("\t",1)[-1][:-1])
        break
```

Answer (score 7):

And here's this vehicle reinvented. It uses own implementation of scrolled frame widget

```
from tkinter import *


class ScrolledFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        top = Frame(master)  # create top frame, containing all things
        # attach scrollbars
        vscroll = Scrollbar(top)
        vscroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        hscroll = Scrollbar(top, orient='horizontal')
        hscroll.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        # hack: insert self into scrollable canvas
        canvas = Canvas(top, highlightthickness=0)
        canvas.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        super().__init__(master=canvas, *args, **kwargs)  # create
        canvas.create_window(0,0, window=self,
                             anchor='nw', tags='frame')  # insert
        # add a hack to rebuild scrollable area size
        canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.__set_scroll)
        # cross-bind scrolling
        vscroll['command'] = canvas.yview
        canvas['yscrollcommand'] = vscroll.set
        hscroll['command'] = canvas.xview
        canvas['xscrollcommand'] = hscroll.set
        # attach hierarchically
        self._top = top
        self._top._vscroll = vscroll
        self._top._hscroll = hscroll
        self._top._canvas = canvas

    def pack(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''
        A wrapper over tkinter's pack
        '''
        return self._top.pack(*args, **kwargs) # pack topmost

    def __set_scroll(self, event=None):
        canvas = self._top._canvas
        canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('frame'))

def showcolors(colors):
    colors = colors[:]
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Tkinter colors showcase')
    Label(root, text='Double click to copy to clipboard').pack(fill='x')
    top = ScrolledFrame(root)
    colnum = int((len(colors)/3) ** 0.5)
    row = 0
    while colors:
        chunk, colors = colors[:colnum], colors[colnum:]
        for col, color in enumerate(chunk):
            lab = Label(top, text=color, bg=color)
            lab.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky='wens')
            lab.bind('<Double-1>', _clipboard_copy(lab))
            lab.bind('<Enter>', lambda ev, lab=lab: lab.config(fg='white'))
            lab.bind('<Leave>', lambda ev, lab=lab: lab.config(fg='black'))
        row += 1
    top.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()

def _clipboard_copy(inst):
    def wrapper(event):
        inst.clipboard_clear()
        inst.clipboard_append(inst['text'])
    return wrapper



COLORS = ['snow', 'ghost white', 'white smoke', 'gainsboro', 'floral white', 'old lace',
          'linen', 'antique white', 'papaya whip', 'blanched almond', 'bisque', 'peach puff',
          'navajo white', 'lemon chiffon', 'mint cream', 'azure', 'alice blue', 'lavender',
          'lavender blush', 'misty rose', 'dark slate gray', 'dim gray', 'slate gray',
          'light slate gray', 'gray', 'light grey', 'midnight blue', 'navy', 'cornflower blue', 'dark slate blue',
          'slate blue', 'medium slate blue', 'light slate blue', 'medium blue', 'royal blue',  'blue',
          'dodger blue', 'deep sky blue', 'sky blue', 'light sky blue', 'steel blue', 'light steel blue',
          'light blue', 'powder blue', 'pale turquoise', 'dark turquoise', 'medium turquoise', 'turquoise',
          'cyan', 'light cyan', 'cadet blue', 'medium aquamarine', 'aquamarine', 'dark green', 'dark olive green',
          'dark sea green', 'sea green', 'medium sea green', 'light sea green', 'pale green', 'spring green',
          'lawn green', 'medium spring green', 'green yellow', 'lime green', 'yellow green',
          'forest green', 'olive drab', 'dark khaki', 'khaki', 'pale goldenrod', 'light goldenrod yellow',
          'light yellow', 'yellow', 'gold', 'light goldenrod', 'goldenrod', 'dark goldenrod', 'rosy brown',
          'indian red', 'saddle brown', 'sandy brown',
          'dark salmon', 'salmon', 'light salmon', 'orange', 'dark orange',
          'coral', 'light coral', 'tomato', 'orange red', 'red', 'hot pink', 'deep pink', 'pink', 'light pink',
          'pale violet red', 'maroon', 'medium violet red', 'violet red',
          'medium orchid', 'dark orchid', 'dark violet', 'blue violet', 'purple', 'medium purple',
          'thistle', 'snow2', 'snow3',
          'snow4', 'seashell2', 'seashell3', 'seashell4', 'AntiqueWhite1', 'AntiqueWhite2',
          'AntiqueWhite3', 'AntiqueWhite4', 'bisque2', 'bisque3', 'bisque4', 'PeachPuff2',
          'PeachPuff3', 'PeachPuff4', 'NavajoWhite2', 'NavajoWhite3', 'NavajoWhite4',
          'LemonChiffon2', 'LemonChiffon3', 'LemonChiffon4', 'cornsilk2', 'cornsilk3',
          'cornsilk4', 'ivory2', 'ivory3', 'ivory4', 'honeydew2', 'honeydew3', 'honeydew4',
          'LavenderBlush2', 'LavenderBlush3', 'LavenderBlush4', 'MistyRose2', 'MistyRose3',
          'MistyRose4', 'azure2', 'azure3', 'azure4', 'SlateBlue1', 'SlateBlue2', 'SlateBlue3',
          'SlateBlue4', 'RoyalBlue1', 'RoyalBlue2', 'RoyalBlue3', 'RoyalBlue4', 'blue2', 'blue4',
          'DodgerBlue2', 'DodgerBlue3', 'DodgerBlue4', 'SteelBlue1', 'SteelBlue2',
          'SteelBlue3', 'SteelBlue4', 'DeepSkyBlue2', 'DeepSkyBlue3', 'DeepSkyBlue4',
          'SkyBlue1', 'SkyBlue2', 'SkyBlue3', 'SkyBlue4', 'LightSkyBlue1', 'LightSkyBlue2',
          'LightSkyBlue3', 'LightSkyBlue4', 'SlateGray1', 'SlateGray2', 'SlateGray3',
          'SlateGray4', 'LightSteelBlue1', 'LightSteelBlue2', 'LightSteelBlue3',
          'LightSteelBlue4', 'LightBlue1', 'LightBlue2', 'LightBlue3', 'LightBlue4',
          'LightCyan2', 'LightCyan3', 'LightCyan4', 'PaleTurquoise1', 'PaleTurquoise2',
          'PaleTurquoise3', 'PaleTurquoise4', 'CadetBlue1', 'CadetBlue2', 'CadetBlue3',
          'CadetBlue4', 'turquoise1', 'turquoise2', 'turquoise3', 'turquoise4', 'cyan2', 'cyan3',
          'cyan4', 'DarkSlateGray1', 'DarkSlateGray2', 'DarkSlateGray3', 'DarkSlateGray4',
          'aquamarine2', 'aquamarine4', 'DarkSeaGreen1', 'DarkSeaGreen2', 'DarkSeaGreen3',
          'DarkSeaGreen4', 'SeaGreen1', 'SeaGreen2', 'SeaGreen3', 'PaleGreen1', 'PaleGreen2',
          'PaleGreen3', 'PaleGreen4', 'SpringGreen2', 'SpringGreen3', 'SpringGreen4',
          'green2', 'green3', 'green4', 'chartreuse2', 'chartreuse3', 'chartreuse4',
          'OliveDrab1', 'OliveDrab2', 'OliveDrab4', 'DarkOliveGreen1', 'DarkOliveGreen2',
          'DarkOliveGreen3', 'DarkOliveGreen4', 'khaki1', 'khaki2', 'khaki3', 'khaki4',
          'LightGoldenrod1', 'LightGoldenrod2', 'LightGoldenrod3', 'LightGoldenrod4',
          'LightYellow2', 'LightYellow3', 'LightYellow4', 'yellow2', 'yellow3', 'yellow4',
          'gold2', 'gold3', 'gold4', 'goldenrod1', 'goldenrod2', 'goldenrod3', 'goldenrod4',
          'DarkGoldenrod1', 'DarkGoldenrod2', 'DarkGoldenrod3', 'DarkGoldenrod4',
          'RosyBrown1', 'RosyBrown2', 'RosyBrown3', 'RosyBrown4', 'IndianRed1', 'IndianRed2',
          'IndianRed3', 'IndianRed4', 'sienna1', 'sienna2', 'sienna3', 'sienna4', 'burlywood1',
          'burlywood2', 'burlywood3', 'burlywood4', 'wheat1', 'wheat2', 'wheat3', 'wheat4', 'tan1',
          'tan2', 'tan4', 'chocolate1', 'chocolate2', 'chocolate3', 'firebrick1', 'firebrick2',
          'firebrick3', 'firebrick4', 'brown1', 'brown2', 'brown3', 'brown4', 'salmon1', 'salmon2',
          'salmon3', 'salmon4', 'LightSalmon2', 'LightSalmon3', 'LightSalmon4', 'orange2',
          'orange3', 'orange4', 'DarkOrange1', 'DarkOrange2', 'DarkOrange3', 'DarkOrange4',
          'coral1', 'coral2', 'coral3', 'coral4', 'tomato2', 'tomato3', 'tomato4', 'OrangeRed2',
          'OrangeRed3', 'OrangeRed4', 'red2', 'red3', 'red4', 'DeepPink2', 'DeepPink3', 'DeepPink4',
          'HotPink1', 'HotPink2', 'HotPink3', 'HotPink4', 'pink1', 'pink2', 'pink3', 'pink4',
          'LightPink1', 'LightPink2', 'LightPink3', 'LightPink4', 'PaleVioletRed1',
          'PaleVioletRed2', 'PaleVioletRed3', 'PaleVioletRed4', 'maroon1', 'maroon2',
          'maroon3', 'maroon4', 'VioletRed1', 'VioletRed2', 'VioletRed3', 'VioletRed4',
          'magenta2', 'magenta3', 'magenta4', 'orchid1', 'orchid2', 'orchid3', 'orchid4', 'plum1',
          'plum2', 'plum3', 'plum4', 'MediumOrchid1', 'MediumOrchid2', 'MediumOrchid3',
          'MediumOrchid4', 'DarkOrchid1', 'DarkOrchid2', 'DarkOrchid3', 'DarkOrchid4',
          'purple1', 'purple2', 'purple3', 'purple4', 'MediumPurple1', 'MediumPurple2',
          'MediumPurple3', 'MediumPurple4', 'thistle1', 'thistle2', 'thistle3', 'thistle4',
          'gray1', 'gray2', 'gray3', 'gray4', 'gray5', 'gray6', 'gray7', 'gray8', 'gray9', 'gray10',
          'gray11', 'gray12', 'gray13', 'gray14', 'gray15', 'gray16', 'gray17', 'gray18', 'gray19',
          'gray20', 'gray21', 'gray22', 'gray23', 'gray24', 'gray25', 'gray26', 'gray27', 'gray28',
          'gray29', 'gray30', 'gray31', 'gray32', 'gray33', 'gray34', 'gray35', 'gray36', 'gray37',
          'gray38', 'gray39', 'gray40', 'gray42', 'gray43', 'gray44', 'gray45', 'gray46', 'gray47',
          'gray48', 'gray49', 'gray50', 'gray51', 'gray52', 'gray53', 'gray54', 'gray55', 'gray56',
          'gray57', 'gray58', 'gray59', 'gray60', 'gray61', 'gray62', 'gray63', 'gray64', 'gray65',
          'gray66', 'gray67', 'gray68', 'gray69', 'gray70', 'gray71', 'gray72', 'gray73', 'gray74',
          'gray75', 'gray76', 'gray77', 'gray78', 'gray79', 'gray80', 'gray81', 'gray82', 'gray83',
          'gray84', 'gray85', 'gray86', 'gray87', 'gray88', 'gray89', 'gray90', 'gray91', 'gray92',
          'gray93', 'gray94', 'gray95', 'gray97', 'gray98', 'gray99']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    showcolors(COLORS)
```

It's something like Tcl/Tk's showcase, but pythonic)
[image: Tkinter colors showcase]

Answer (score 3):

Incorporating some of the other answers into a definitive version complete with:

- scrolling;
- copying color hexcode to clipboard;
- using a built-in color list;
- white text on dark colors;
- adjusting for modern high-DPI displays;

The [official tkinter colors man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/colors.html) is derived from the [X11 color names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names), and a version should be included in your python installation under `%PYTHONPATH%/Tools/pynche/X/rgb.txt` . Here is a [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023) on the formulas used to calculate a proper text color based on [contrast](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#contrast-ratiodef) and [luminance](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#relativeluminancedef).

```
import tkinter as tk
from Tools.pynche import ColorDB
import os
import colorsys

rgb_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(ColorDB.__file__), 'X', 'rgb.txt')
rgb_db = ColorDB.get_colordb(rgb_file)
colors = [x.lower().replace(' ', '') for x in rgb_db.unique_names()]

# Separating the grayscale looks nicer
grayscale = []
for v in ['black'] + ['gray{}'.format(i) for i in range(0, 101)] + ['white']:
    if v in colors:
        colors.remove(v)
        grayscale.append(v)
colors.sort(key=lambda x: colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*rgb_db.find_byname(x)))
colors = grayscale + colors

# Use white on dark colors, black on light
def calculateContrast(color):
    # Converting to 8 bit from 16 bit, and diving by 255 (255 * 256 = 65280)
    rgb = [c / 65280 for c in color]
    r, g, b = [(c / 12.92) if c <= 0.03928 else
               ((c + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4 for c in rgb]
    luminance = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b
    if luminance > 0.179:
        return '#000000'
    else:
        return '#ffffff'

class ColorGrid(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL,
                                   command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw')
        self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.frame, anchor='nw')
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._onFrameConfigure)

        columns = 8
        rows = len(colors) // columns + 1
        max_width = len(max(colors, key=lambda x: len(x)))
        for i, color in enumerate(colors):
            fg_color = calculateContrast(root.winfo_rgb(color))
            # Pseudo-label, allows for easy changing of border color
            entry = tk.Entry(self.frame, width=max_width, justify=tk.CENTER,
                             relief=tk.FLAT, disabledbackground=color,
                             disabledforeground=fg_color, cursor='arrow',
                             highlightbackground=color, highlightthickness=3)
            entry.insert(0, color)
            entry.config(state='disabled')
            entry.grid(row=i % rows, column=i // rows, sticky="ew")
            entry.bind('<Double-1>', self._clipboard_copy)
            entry.bind('<Enter>', lambda event, widget=entry: widget.config(
                       highlightbackground=widget['disabledforeground']))
            entry.bind('<Leave>', lambda event, widget=entry: widget.config(
                       highlightbackground=widget['disabledbackground']))

        self.canvas.update()
        new_height = min(self.winfo_screenheight() * 2 // 3,
                         self.canvas.bbox('all')[3])
        self.canvas.config(width=self.canvas.bbox('all')[2],
                           yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set, height=new_height)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event:
                             self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * event.delta),
                                                      'units'))

    # Copy hex code to clipboard
    def _clipboard_copy(self, event):
        entry = event.widget
        rgb_tuple = self.winfo_rgb(entry.get())
        hex_code = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*[i // 256 for i in rgb_tuple])
        self.clipboard_clear()
        self.clipboard_append(hex_code)

    def _onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Better readability on high DPI displays
    try:
        from ctypes import windll
        windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
    except Exception:
        pass
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Named Color Chart")
    ColorGrid(root).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I couldn't tell for other distros, but for nowadays Debian testing, I had to install the `python3-examples` package and then add `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/share/doc/python3.9/examples/` to my environment variables (trying to reduce the impact of that new path variable to the maximum) and finally replace line `from Tools.pynche import ColorDB` with `from pynche import ColorDB` at the beginning of the code.