# Portable method to get a list of accepted color names with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, portability

It seems that Python Tkinter and Tcl/Tk ask the system for color names and do not maintain it themselves.  Looking at the standard Python/Tcl/Tk sources does not show any of those colors. You can only find them in `color.n` which is part of the Tk documentation and in an optional `pygment` library.

Is there a **portable** way to ask the system itself (and not any other source which might or might not match the system one) through Python and Tkinter or any other GUI library, for a list of the available color names?

This was previously marked as a duplicate of [Named colors in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539993/named-colors-in-tkinter), but the only answer there involves reading `/etc` and so is Linux-specific.  I am looking for a portable method that would work with Linux, Windows, and Mac.

Comment: Why would you need exact names when you can use `'#048cf0'`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539993/named-colors-in-tkinter

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, I wonder how the answer you tagged is sufficient : It only concerns Debian has zero portability !!!  What about windows and mac users ?

Comment: While I understand where this question is coming from, does it essentially matter what each system calls the very same color? It's not the system that defines how a color is perceived, it is _physics_.

Comment: @Nae : We should avoid restricting ourselves to the way a color is perceived. computer programming and understanding reality is not only about the way thing are displayed or perceived, but about the relationship between various kind of stimuli.

For an example, those names are not necessarily about name of colors, but can also be related with the apparence of a specific theme or  about the standard names the system provide. If you want to make a program to display all color names provided by the system, there is absolutely no point in being able to code an hex value.

Comment: @Camion Even if you found the same color name on two systems, there's no guarantee they would produce the same color. The hex value is at least *unambiguous* (ignoring monitor calibration).

Comment: @chepner, As told above. I'm not looking for a way to get same displayed color. I'd like to get the system colors names which might be used to set in a drop list for an example, or to provide colors related with the current color theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can validate the color :  `widget.winfo_rgb('color')`

If color string is wrong the error arises

Comment: OK, but how can I get a list of all possible color names to check them ?

Comment: I was not able to find a list of color names embeded in tkinter but all I needed was to check if color exist. It appeared to be a better solution in my case as you can do  `widget.winfo_rgb('RED')` or `widget.winfo_rgb('#ff22ff')`