# Python Tkinter random generating the colors?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, fill

```
from tkinter import *
import random

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

for x in range(0, 40):

    x1 = random.randint(0,400)
    y1 = random.randint(0,400)
    x2 = random.randint(0,400)
    y2 = random.randint(0,400)
    x3 = random.randint(0,400)
    y3 = random.randint(0,400)
    my_triangle = canvas.create_polygon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3,\
                  fill =("blue"), outline="red")
```

Hi! I am playing with tkinter and generating random triangles. The problem is:
I want to use random on fill = " " to generate random colors

random.randint(start, end) returns numbers, but fill accepts only strings like
fill ="red" or hexadecimal = "#RGB"
if I enter a numeric valuer like fill = (1,1,0) it doesn't work. How could I generate random string values in fill?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just stick a whole bunch of color strings in a list, then pick one from the list at random?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `random.sample()` from a known list of colors. And you can find the python tkinter color chart enumerated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4969543/1422451). You can then randomize for both *fill* and *outline* values:

```
COLORS = ['snow', 'ghost white', 'white smoke', 'gainsboro', 'floral white', 'old lace' ...]

for x in range(0, 40):

    x1 = random.randint(0,400)
    y1 = random.randint(0,400)
    x2 = random.randint(0,400)
    y2 = random.randint(0,400)
    x3 = random.randint(0,400)
    y3 = random.randint(0,400)

    my_triangle = canvas.create_polygon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3,\
                  fill = (random.sample(COLORS, 1)[0]), 
                  outline = random.sample(COLORS, 1)[0])
```

[image: Tk Window Output 1]
[image: Tk Window Output 2]
[image: Tk Window Output 3]

Of course, always seed if you want to reproduce same exact random generated numbers:

```
random.seed(444)   # WHERE 444 IS ANY INTEGER
```

Answer (score 0):

In alternative just generate your random color and format it:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def random_color():
    return random.randint(0,0x1000000)

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

for x in range(0, 40):

    color = '{:06x}'.format(random_color())
    x1 = random.randint(0,400)
    y1 = random.randint(0,400)
    x2 = random.randint(0,400)
    y2 = random.randint(0,400)
    x3 = random.randint(0,400)
    y3 = random.randint(0,400)
    my_triangle = canvas.create_polygon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3,\
                  fill =('#'+ color), outline="red")

tk.mainloop()
```