# Pick color that's further away from white

Tags: javascript, colors

I'm getting the computed HEX of the color and background color of `body` like so:

```
function rgb2hex(rgb){
  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i);
  return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : '';
}


var color = rgb2hex(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).color);
var bg = rgb2hex(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).backgroundColor);
```

I need to pick one of these colors to be used as a text color on a white background. However, a problem occurs when the page background is dark and the color is light/white. Therefore, I need to intelligently pick one of these to be used as the text color.

How can I find out which one of `color` and `bg` is furthest away from `#fff`?

Comment: Furthest away in what sense? You want to select the most-contrasting colour?

Comment: That's exactly correct. Which one of those two colors is most visually suitable to be used as the text `color` when `background: #fff;`

Comment: Would using CSS invert property ( https://davidwalsh.name/invert-colors-css ) do what you want? It you want a javascript function it is a matter of figuring out how to do the inversion in javascript. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961725/algorithm-for-calculating-inverse-color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formula to determine brightness of RGB color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color)

Comment: Using the formula in the link `0.2126*R + 0.7152*G + 0.0722*B` to calculate the luminance of both colors and then pick the one with the smallest luminance (the darkest of both or as you said _the furthest from white_)!

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate [relative luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) of both colors. Color with the lower luminance, will be the one further from white. Formula for this calculation is provided in the linked article and in my code below:

```js
{
    const getRGBLuminance = (string) => {
        const rgb = string.replace(/[^\d ]/g, '').split(' ');
        return 0.2126 * rgb[0] + 0.7152 * rgb[1] + 0.0722 * rgb[2];
    }

    const bodyStyle        = window.getComputedStyle(document.body),
          colorLuminance   = getRGBLuminance(bodyStyle.color),
          bgColorLuminance = getRGBLuminance(bodyStyle.backgroundColor);

    if (colorLuminance < bgColorLuminance) {
        console.log('Text color is further from #FFF.');
    }
    else if (colorLuminance > bgColorLuminance) {
        console.log('Background color is further from #FFF.');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Both color and background color are equally far from #FFF.');
    }
}
```

```css
/* Only for demonstration */
body {
  background-color: #ACE;
  color: #000;
}
```