# Decide whether textColor should be white or black based on background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to determine whether a textColor should be black or white based on the background color, but it seem not to work. first of all i've created an extension which retrieve the rgb values. then i use below algorithm to calculate and then determine if the value is above 186. The issue is that everytime i run the algorithm it always return something around 1, which is way below the 186 which should be the middle which determine if text should be black or white. What am i doing wrong in order to calculate a value around 186? which i've found is what determine if it black or white from this question

[How to decide font color in white or black depending on background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942878/how-to-decide-font-color-in-white-or-black-depending-on-background-color)

**Extenstion**

```
extension UIColor {
    var components:(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        var r:CGFloat = 0
        var g:CGFloat = 0
        var b:CGFloat = 0
        var a:CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        return (r,g,b,a)
    }
}
```

**ViewDidLoad**

```
    let colorComp = UIColor(rgba: "#f2f2f2").components
    let colorCheck = colorComp.red * 0.299 + colorComp.green * 0.587 + colorComp.blue * 0.114
    print(colorCheck)
```

in this case `red`, `green` and `blue` returns `0.949019607843137` each.

Comment: That seems right.  `components` is defined to return a value between 0.0 and 1.0.  The return value you show looks good for 'f2' divided by 'ff'.  If you want a value in the range 0..255, you need to multiply to scale your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RGB range is from 0 (blak) to 255 (white) but in this case the range is 0 to 1. You should calculate the new value with this operation:

Value = (1/255)*186 = 0.729;

0xF2 = 242 dec = 242/255 = 0.949

Comment: So where is it i determine whether it is above or below 186 here?

Comment: After your function "let colorComp = UIColor(rgba: "#f2f2f2").components" you can convert the colorspace from 0.0 / 1.0 into colorspace 1 / 255 of R G and B and then for each color check if the value is > or < 186.