# Javascript - Convert and Display Array of Number into Colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [Color-Thief](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) to extract a color palette from an image. And I've already extracted the colors using JavaScript.

```
<img src="my-image.jpg" id="uploadedImage" alt="Uplaoded Image>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var image = document.getElementById("uploadedImage");
                    var colorThief = new ColorThief();
                    var palette = colorThief.getPalette(image, 8);
                    for (color in palette) {
                        var firstColor = palette[0];
                        var secondColor = palette[1];
                        var thirdColor = palette[2];
                        var fourthColor = palette[3];
                        var fifthColor = palette[4];
                        var sixthColor = palette[5];
                        var seventhColor = palette[6];
                        var eighthColor = palette[7];
                    }

</script>
```

The colors extracted for example are:

```
(7) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0
:
(3) [55, 30, 41]
1
:
(3) [210, 111, 74]
2
:
(3) [121, 196, 212]
3
:
(3) [144, 62, 57]
4
:
(3) [101, 66, 100]
5
:
(3) [189, 174, 192]
6
:
(3) [164, 116, 133]
```

But my problem is that I cannot convert these Arrays into colors to display. Is there any way to do that?

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript), but the answer doesn't help me figure out the way to solve my problem.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb) doesn't consider getting the colors dynamically from images neither displaying the colors. It's just converting from one space to another.

> **SIDE NOTE:** If you want to try the Color-Thief, you have to have a server, because it calls AJAX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Comment: @user3080953 that is the reverse

Comment: @user3080953 The possible duplicate is the opposite of what I am asking.

Comment: No, it asks for both directions, and the accepted answer gives exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses jQuery to set the background color of a bunch of `div` to the colors in the array.

```js
var colorData = [
  [55, 30, 41],
  [210, 111, 74],
  [121, 196, 212],
  [144, 62, 57],
  [101, 66, 100],
  [189, 174, 192],
  [164, 116, 133]
];
$(function() {
  var $placeholder = $("#placeholder");
  var $tmp;
  $.each(colorData, function(idx, elem) {
    $tmp = $("<div class='colorize'></div>");
    $tmp.css("background-color", "rgb(" + this[0] + "," + this[1] + "," + this[2] + ")");
    //$tmp.append($("<span>").text($tmp.css('background-color')));
    $tmp.append($("<span>").text("#" +
      twoDigitHex(this[0]) +
      twoDigitHex(this[1]) +
      twoDigitHex(this[2])));
    $placeholder.append($tmp);
  });
});

function twoDigitHex(val) {
  return ("00" + val.toString(16)).substr(-2).toUpperCase();
}
```

```css
div.colorize {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
}

div.colorize>span {
  position: relative;
  top: 75px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='placeholder'></div>
```

Edit: adjusted snippet to put background color as text

Edit: variable font color [(black | white)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942878/how-to-decide-font-color-in-white-or-black-depending-on-background-color)

Edit: change text to put it in a span, position that span under the div.

Edit: as requested combined a few different answers to this question to display the HEX color value instead of RGB.

**Edit: Combined the other answers in to this question to hopefully create a more succinct and understandable variant below;**

```js
var colorData = [
  [55, 30, 41],
  [210, 111, 74],
  [121, 196, 212],
  [144, 62, 57],
  [101, 66, 100],
  [189, 174, 192],
  [164, 116, 133]
];
$(function() {
  colorData.map(([r, g, b]) => {
    displaySwatch(`#${twoDigitHex(r)}${twoDigitHex(g)}${twoDigitHex(b)}`);
  });
});

function displaySwatch(hex) {
  var $placeholder = $("#placeholder");
  var $tmp = $("<div class='colorize'></div>");
  $tmp.css("background-color", hex);
  $tmp.append($("<span>").text(hex));
  $placeholder.append($tmp);
}

function twoDigitHex(val) {
  return ("00" + val.toString(16)).substr(-2).toUpperCase();
}
```

```css
div.colorize {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
}

div.colorize>span {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 8pt;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='placeholder'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Works like a charm (Y). You saved the day.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to display the color code as well with the colored box? I mean beneath the colored box.

Comment: I can't preview the color code in hex; the text inside or beneath the colored box. I get [object object] instead when I convert the color space to hex. Can you help me please ?

Comment: combined parts of Dekel's answer and Yasser's to produce the hex value for display.

Answer (score 3):

If you have array of arrays, where each of the sub arrays has 3 items representing the R, B and G, you can convert them to hexadecimal notation using the link in your question:

```js
ar = [
  [55, 30, 41],
  [210, 111, 74],
  [121, 196, 212],
  [144, 62, 57],
  [101, 66, 100],
  [189, 174, 192],
  [164, 116, 133]
]
res = ar.map(([r, g, b]) => ["#", r.toString(16), g.toString(16), b.toString(16)].join(""))
console.log(res);

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = res.map((color) => `<div class='color-box' style='background: ${color};'></div>`).join("")
```

```css
div.color-box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Consider using array destructuring `ar.map(([r, g, b]) => ...`

Comment: You'll also want to do zero padding for when values are less than 16.

Comment: I want to display the colors either in the HEX or in the RGB Format. The color space doesn't matter my case.

Comment: @OsamaAbbas so what is the problem with the above answer?

Comment: @vox I'm not sure I understand the comment. Can you explain please?

Comment: @Dekel Okay, let my clarify as much as my English can :D. Your answer converts the Array of 3 numbers [x,y,z] to RRGGBB. Your solution is much better than the other solutions from the questions I added. But What I want is to convert this Array (color) to something like a palette as in the Color-Thief site does when you press the `click button`

Comment: Explain where/what exactly is the problem. Creating the HTML? extract the colors? Convert from rgb to hex?

Comment: @Dekel Previewing the colors is the problem.

Comment: @Dekel,  after the many modifications the OP has asked for to my answer I think yours could be made to more succinctly handle all the additional requests.

Answer (score 1):

Dekel's answer should work fine in most cases. I have made only a minor addition to his answer. The numbers can be < 16, so they have to be padded with a "0" to be treated as color values.

```js
ar = [
  [9, 8, 7],
  [55, 30, 41],
  [210, 111, 74],
  [121, 196, 212],
  [144, 62, 57],
  [101, 66, 100],
  [189, 174, 192],
  [164, 116, 133]
]

function toPaddedHexVal(val) {
  var hexVal = val.toString(16);
  return hexVal.length < 2 ? "0" + hexVal : hexVal;
}

res = ar.map(colorArray => "#" + colorArray.map(toPaddedHexVal).join(""))
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript colors may be specified by strings; for example, `'red'` and `'#123456'`. Since you have the primary values, you could build a color specification string from, say, `firstColor`, as follows:

```
var colorSpecification = 'rgb(' + firstColor[0].toString() + ',' + firstColor[1].toString() + ',' + firstColor[2].toString() + ')';
```

For your example, that should produce a string value of `'rgb(55,30,41)'`.

Be advised that JavaScript color specification is somewhat arcane. While specifications such as `'rgb(10,20,30)'`, `'#123456'`, and `'#12345678'` are accepted, so are specifications such as `'red'`, `'yellow'`, and `'blue'`. Even `'chucknorris'` is reputed to be acceptable!