# How to get the ForeColor associated with the BackColor of the skin?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

When you set a `SimpleButton.Appearance.BackColor` property to a `DX Skin` color (`@Danger`, `@Question`, `@Success`, `@Primary` or `@Info` as shown in the image):

[image: Color selector]

The `SimpleButton.Appearance.ForeColor` property is evaluated at run-time with the appropriate color (if the skin color is too dark, Color.White would be used; if the skin color is too bright, Color.Black would be used):

Dark `@Success`:

[image: Dark]

Light `@Success`:

[image: Light]

How do I get this `ForeColor` that is evaluated in run-time?

I have tried getting `SimpleButton.ForeColor`, `SimpleButton.Appearance.ForeColor` and `SimpleButton.Appearance.GetForeColor(e.GraphicsCache)` (I'm trying to get this color inside a `CustomDraw` event) but it's always `Color.Black`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this extension method according to [this implementation of the W3C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/9453080), making some [modifications](https://jsfiddle.net/q781qx52/) per [Miral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43534/miral)'s tests:

```
public static Color GetContrastColor(this Color color)
{
    return (color.R * 0.299M) + (color.G * 0.587M) + (color.B * 0.114M) > 149 ? 
        Color.Black : 
        Color.White;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DevExpress.LookAndFeel.DXSkinColors.ForeColors.Information property should offer the ForeColor for the Information/Success coloring.

Comment: You're correct--this is getting the back color. My mistake, sorry.

Comment: This is also giving me the green-ish color (same as `BackColor`)!

Comment: Are you using SVG skins/palettes or the Bitmap GDI skin? In my test, the fore color IS a green-ish color, just a lighter shade than the actual button.

Comment: I'm using The Beziere skin with the Leaf Rustle pallet that has the `SimpleButton` `ForeColor` set to `Color.White` (as in the question), but the end-user can change pallets. So if the user selects, say, the High Contrast White pallet, then the `SimpleButton` `ForeColor` changes to `Color.Black`. I want to get the black or white color depending on the skin