# What is the minimum distance between two colors to be easily distinguishable?

Tags: user-experience, readability

I need to draw a Sierpinski Triangle for some homework.
The task includes a random color picker for the triangle. As the background is white this may lead to problems with visibility.

My question is what is the minimum distance between two rgb values for them to still be easily distinguishable?

I am aware that this is rather subjective and depends on monitor, ambient light and the definition of "easily distinguishable" but a rough estimate would suffice. Web searches were mostly concerned with physical distance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This seems like more of a graphic design problem than a programming problem. Have you tried [graphic design se](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @jsotola I was only trying to add some pointless complexity to some programming homework and maybe learn a bit about color usage. The triangle I'm supposed to render is directly on a white background.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the tip, stackoverflow seemed like first instinct when there's a problem with stuff with code, I'll check it out and edit my post to link to any responses there(if it isn't removed before).

Comment: maybe one of the values in the fractal equations can be used as a basis for color selection

Comment: Check out this answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/4329824