# Detect color is light or dark in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, colors

Is there any way to check color is dark or ligh , in the sense black tone or white in flutter and get a boolean value true or false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decide font color in white or black depending on background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942878/how-to-decide-font-color-in-white-or-black-depending-on-background-color)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check whether color is dark or light, we will need to convert that color into its greyscale color. Formula to find grayscale of any color from its RGB value is:

**grayscale = (0.299 * Red) + (0.587 * Green) + (0.114 * Blue)**

And than check:

```
if(grayscale > 128){
    // color is light
}else{
    // color is dark
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can also use the approach to take the luminance and apply the threshold specified by the W3C. In dart code this can look like this:

```
Color getFontColorForBackground(Color background) {
  return (background.computeLuminance() > 0.179)? Colors.black : Colors.white;
}
```

More background information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/3041394