# Flutter exception on generate color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In my app there is a group chat where each user has it's own color on their name just like Whatsapp group chat. But there are times where the name color blends with the background color (e.g yellow user name on a white bubble chat) which makes it difficult for users to read.

Here is the code where I generate the color:

```
for(var item in json.decode(conversation!.idReceiversGroup!)){
  if(!bubbleColor.map((e) => e.idUser).contains(item)){
     bubbleColor.add(BubbleColor(idUser: item, Color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]));
  }
}
```

Is there any solutions?

Comment: What type of Exception are you facing?

Comment: Light colors @Dani3le_

Comment: Maybe you should add some shadow to your `Text` (user name) to highlight it more.

Comment: so the only way is to add shadow? @AnteBule

Comment: Probably not the only way but one of the possibilities that occurred to me.

Comment: ah okey, but is there a way to give conditional to not generate the light colors? @AnteBule

Comment: Maybe try checking like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68170447/detect-color-is-light-or-dark-in-flutter