# What is the color contrast algorithm that Plotly uses to determine the label text color on a given background?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

(This is a duplicate of [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/what-is-the-color-contrast-algorithm-that-plotly-uses-to-determine-the-label-text-color-on-a-given-background/78702?u=avinoamsn) question on Plotly's forums.)

Here is an example of a labeled bar chart. Note that the label on the dark blue bar is colored white:

[image]

I’d like to duplicate this label contrast behavior in the annotations. I’ve implemented the contrast algorithm detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942878/how-to-decide-font-color-in-white-or-black-depending-on-background-color/3943023#3943023), but this yields slightly different results:

[image]

(Note that the label on the light blue bar at the bottom is now white, in addition to the label on the dark blue bar.)

Is there a way to access the contrast/color value that Plotly is generating for each label? If not, where in the codebase (or online) might I be able to find the contrast algorithm that Plotly uses to determine the label text color?

Comment: The function you're looking for seems to be [`color.contrast`](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/v2.26.1/src/components/color/index.js#L64), which uses some tinycolor2 [functions](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor/blob/master/tinycolor.js#L47).

Comment: Perfect, thank you @kikon!