How to prevent black colour in a cell
I have a schedule macro and I loop to give random colours to each cell of the first row and name titles in them.
However, sometimes by random, black colour appears, which is not useful as content is also black.
How can I avoid black (and potentially close to black colours where content is not visible)
Following is my part of my current code (I dont put the entire for loop, as it is not pertinent here, but this code basically loops for every cell of the first row):
With ActiveSheet
    rg.Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Font.Size = 18
        .ColumnWidth = 30
        .RowHeight = 80
        .Interior.ColorIndex = Int((56 * Rnd) + 1)
    End With
End With


Not an expert, but perhaps it's possible to assign a variable  that you check against a list of numbers that have dark colours? Something like: RandColor = Int((56 * Rnd) + 1) and If RandColor = 1 Then RandColor + 1 (Can't figure it out myself though).

Or keep an array of dark colours and change the text to white when the cell is one of those colours (black being very hard to read on any dark colour)

Would RandColor = Int((55 * Rnd) + 2)  work? (Not tested)

I had tried Int((56Rnd)+2) and it had given error a few times, when random number went out of limits, so dont know if Int((55Rnd)+2) will work.

You could do something like create a variable for your random colour
Dim RandCol As Integer    
RandCol = Int((56 * Rnd) + 1)

and then loop that until it doesn't equal 1
Do Until RandCol <> 1
    RandCol = Int((56 * Rnd) + 1)
Loop

or just do it once more
if RandCol = 1 then
    RandCol = Int((56 * Rnd) + 1)
end if

and then use that as your colour index
.Interior.ColorIndex = RandCol 


The probably easiest way is to create an array of valid color index values and create a random number to pick a color from that array.
Function getRandomColorindex() As Long
    Dim validColors
    validColors = Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, _
                       12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, _
                       20, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, _
                       31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, _
                       40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, _
                       50, 53, 54)

    Dim i As Long
    i = Int((UBound(validColors) + 1) * Rnd)
    getRandomColorindex = validColors(i)
End Function

Adapt the array definition to your needs: If there are any colors you don't want, just remove them. If there are any colors I omitted but you want, add them. To have only 4 colors,
Note that you don't need to use Select to work on the range
With rg
    (... set all your properties.. )
    .Interior.colorIndex = getRandomColorindex
End With 

An alternative could be to use all colors (even black), but change the font color to white if a background color is too dark. The following function will tell if a background color should use black or white text color, it is adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/7599798
Public Function isDarkColor(color As Long)
    Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long
    getRGB color, r, g, b
    
    isDarkColor = ((r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114) < 130)
End Function

And your code would change to
With rg
    (... set all your properties.. )
    .Interior.colorIndex = Int((56 * Rnd) + 1)
    .Font.color = IIf(isDarkColor(.Interior.color), vbWhite, vbBlack)
End With 

