# C# remove darker colors from KnownColor

Tags: c#, colors

I got a list of Knowncolor from the system but I want to remove some which are too dark and make the foreground character unseen. I tried the following code but KnownColor.Black still shows up. Is there anyway to order them by their darkness?

```
if (knownColor > KnownColor.Transparent && knownColor < KnownColor.MidnightBlue && knownColor < KnownColor.Navy)
            {
                //add it to our list
                colors.Add(knownColor);
            }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert the known colors to a Color instance and then compare brightness using the [`GetBrightness()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getbrightness.aspx) method:

> Gets the hue-saturation-brightness
>   (HSB) brightness value for this Color
>   structure.
>   The brightness ranges from 0.0 through
>   Blockquote
>   1.0, where 0.0 represents black and 1.0 represents white.

```
float brightness = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Transparent).GetBrightness();
```

Applied to your example, something like the following should work (tested for black and yellow):

```
KnownColor knownColor = KnownColor.Yellow;

float transparentBrightness = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Transparent).GetBrightness();
float midnightBlueBrightness = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.MidnightBlue).GetBrightness();
float navyBrightness = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Navy).GetBrightness();
float knownColorBrightness = Color.FromKnownColor(knownColor).GetBrightness();

if (knownColorBrightness  < transparentBrightness 
    && knownColorBrightness > midnightBlueBrightness 
    && knownColorBrightness > navyBrightness)
{
    //add it to our list
    colors.Add(knownColor);
}
```

Comment: Commenting because KnownColor is my internet handle.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at my answer regarding determining a foreground color - it involves calculating the perceived brightness of the background color to decide whether to display white or black as a foreground. You could use the same method and simply choose to eliminate the colors too dark:

[Make foregroundcolor black or white depending on background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241447/make-foregroundcolor-black-or-white-depending-on-background/2241471#2241471)