# How can I find the perfect text color for any given RGB backlight color

Tags: math, colors

Every color has a perfect contrast color black=white, yellow=blue,purple=green, etc..
So how can I find a perfect contrast color for any give rgb value?  Is there a formula or something I can use?

Comment: Are you sure every colour has a universally agreed unique "perfect contrast colour"? According to what source? If you find a source for that claim, likely that source also contains the formula.

Comment: The idea of text in green on purple (or purple on green) is making my eyes water.

Comment: Is the opposite of grey grey?

Comment: Good question I hadn't though of that.

Comment: this might be helpful https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G17.html

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946544/good-text-foreground-color-for-a-given-background-color, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942878/how-to-decide-font-color-in-white-or-black-depending-on-background-color, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116260/given-a-background-color-how-to-get-a-foreground-color-that-makes-it-readable-o, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241447/make-foregroundcolor-black-or-white-depending-on-background, https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/107318/formula-for-color-contrast-between-text-and-background, and many, many more.

Comment: The question of contrasting text and background colors, especially for readability purposes, is a question being debated right now.  For example, according to [this issue on the WCAG issues page](https://github.com/w3c/wcag/issues/695), "color contrast" is only one part of the readability equation and other factors such as font size and font weight also come into play.

Answer (score -1):

Inverting all bits in RGBA will get you an opposite color

```
oppositeColor = ~color & 0xffffff;

 Color     Opposite
#ff0000   #00ffff
#00ff00   #ff00ff
#0000ff   #ffff00
```

Comment: Is #7f7f7f contrast enough to #808080?

Comment: it seems the farther the color is from gray (#FFFFFF / 2) the better contrast will turn out after inverting all bits

Comment: Although this answer makes sense technically, I wouldn't say this is a good method to find a text colour given a background colour. (And that Q has been asked many times at SO and its sister sites.)