# Generating a readable colour from RGB?

Tags: rgb, colors

I'm putting in a function which will allow a user to input a color (eg: purple) and it will change the look of their profile to be purple. It's interpreted from text into a 'Color' class which stores them inside itself as RGB numbers (int for red, one for green and other for blue). What i don't know how to do is logically turn these three numbers into another 3 which will make a readable colour.

Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Joe

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946544/good-text-foreground-color-for-a-given-background-color

Comment: @Mark thanks a lot that helped! Post it as an answer please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you're looking for a readable text color after someone has chosen a background theme color. This was answered in an older question:

[Good text foreground color for a given background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946544/good-text-foreground-color-for-a-given-background-color)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there's not a name for every possible RGB combination!  Presumably you want to find a nearby combination that you *have* specified a name for?

So really all you need is a way of defining how "close" one RGB is to another.  For simplicity, I would suggest Euclidean-distance-squared, i.e. (R2-R1)^2 + (G2-G1)^2 + (B2-B1)^2.  Then all you need to do is iterate through all your "named" colours, and find the one with the smallest distance.

Comment: @Joe Simpson: Oh hang on, by "readable" do you mean "legible", as in "I want to generate a legible foreground colour given an arbitrary background colour"?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [rgb.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) file that comes with X11.

A parser for that could provide a translation between those strings and the RGB values wouldn't be terribly hard to build and would likely do what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry but my parser can already pick up many names and methods for colours

Comment: @Joe what is your question then, exactly? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm trying to turn the RGB values i already parsed into a readable colour

Answer (score 0):

As others already say, there are 16.7 million possible combinations, all of which obviously can't have a defined name.

You're not going into detail about your use case, but if you want to make it end user friendly, how about using percentages?

```
80% red, 50% green, 23% blue
```

this is perfectly understandable for a non-technical person as well. You would limit (from 256^3 to 100^3) the number of possibilities if you use integer percentage values, but not as much as confining the user to a fixed palette of named colours.

Comment: I'm going to add a javascript colour picker when javascript is available