# Text colour calculation for maximum readability PHP/JS/CSS

Tags: php, javascript, css, background-color

Given arbitrary background colour A, the most readable colour for text would be B.

Currently I have the following solution *( that is incredibly popular but **not** correct )*:

```
Turn the bg colour monotone
find the midway point between white and black,
if closer to white
    B = black
else
    B = white.
```

This however is simplistic, fails on the midtones, and does not account for the fact our eyes do not see the colour spectrum uniformly.

I read an article a few months back that explained this and showed demonstrations, showing those colours where the above failed, and the adjusted calculation worked. I cannot find it however.

As a sidenote, people seem to also answer questions like this with an algorithm to figure out contrast between two colours. I have more of those than I could ever want. **I need to know how to produce the best text colour A given background colour B.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this could help you out.

[Good text foreground color for a given background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946544/good-text-foreground-color-for-a-given-background-color)