# Determine most visible foreground color

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good text foreground color for a given background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946544/good-text-foreground-color-for-a-given-background-color)

In the Photoshop color picker, as you pick a color, the selector becomes either black or white depending on which is most visible (See image). What algorithm are they using, particularly, I want to input an rgb value and get back either black or white.

I have tried the following and although it works, it is not as accurate as Photoshop.

```
if (color.makeGray() < 128)
    return white;
else
    return black;
```

[image]

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/946734/5987